# implement shape to display 2D laser scan data

Tags: xaml, canvas, drawing, windows-8.1, shapes

I'm working on a Win8 editor which is basically based on a Canvas and Shapes like Line, Rectangle, etc. on it. Those shapes can be manipulated by the user. Now I want to implement a custom shape that take a list of 2D points from a laser scan (used in architecture).

So my question is, which base primitive would you use to display lets say 500 points? I was thinking of a Path but then I get rather a set of connected lines (path, polygone) instead of just the dots. So what else?

This picture illustrates what I want to achieve. All blue dots should be in one shape that can be dragged by the user.

[image: 2D laser scan sample]

My first guess would be the [PathGeometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751808(v=vs.110).aspx) filled with a lot of RectangleGeometries or EllipseGeometries. But I wonder what this means in terms of performance.

```
<Path Fill="LemonChiffon" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1">
  <Path.Data>
    <RectangleGeometry Rect="50,50,5,5" />
    <RectangleGeometry Rect="60,50,5,5" />
    <RectangleGeometry Rect="70,50,5,5" />
    ...
  </Path.Data>
</Path>
```